WPF, MVVM, How to get screen reader to announce newly added List Box item
I am modifying an existing WPF, MVVM application (using .NET 8) so that it can support screen readers. For ease, and quick testing, I'm using Windows 11 Narrator, but will also be testing with JAWS.
In general this works, however I'm having a problem whereby when a new item is added to a ListBox, or rather added to an ObservableCollection which is bound to the ListBox, the screen reader doesn't announce the newly added item.
This is a pretty major issue for our visually impaired users, because items dynamically added to the list are extremely important and require attention. From a sighted users perspective they can instantly see a newly added item, where-as the visually impaired user receives no notification from a screen reader.
I've managed to get screen reader notification on a small test app by adding the AutomationProperties.LiveSetting to the Listbox in XAML, retrieving the AutomationPeer for the ListBox and raising the AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged when an item is added:
// Do some processing which adds a new item, then retrieve the AutomationPeer to raise the event
var peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(MyListBox);
if (peer != null)
{
  peer.RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged);
}

This works great in my test app (using code behind), and the screen reader notifies the user of the newly added item.
This is easy to achieve in a small test app using code behind. What I'm trying to figure out, and hope someone can point me in the right direction, is how to achieve this using MVVM.
Using MVVM, I have an ObservableCollection in the view model. So, when an item is added to the ObservableCollection, how can I get the AutomationPeer for the ListBox and raise an automation event within my view model?
Maybe I'm trying to go about this the wrong way, I'm fairly new to both WPF and MVVM.
Here's my example:
XAML
<Window x:Class="WpfAppAccessibilityTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppAccessibilityTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox AutomationProperties.LiveSetting="Assertive" AutomationProperties.Name="My list of things" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStuff}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Code Behind
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfAppAccessibilityTest
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher;

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

            // Simulate handling some event that occurs in the future
            Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    ListOfStuff.Add("Item2")
                    // How do I raise an AutomationPeer event here so screen reader will anounce the newly added item?
                );
            });
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfStuff { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Item1" };

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
    }
}

I've checked this question but none of the answers seemed suitable - I am able to get a screen reader announcing, I just can't figure out how to do it from the view model.

Chain off the ObservableCollection's "Changed" event. (And maybe set the SelectedIndex or whatever) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=net-8.0

@GerrySchmitz, unless I am misunderstanding what you mean, I have full control over when the item is added to the ObservableCollection so don't need to handle the changed event.At the point in the ViewModel where the item is added (ObservableCollection.Add) I need to get the AutomationPeer for the Listbox. It's this part I am unable to achieve from the ViewModel.

If you have "full control of the Add", you would know that the instant it is added to the ObservableCollection (OC), it also appears in the ListBox. Since you should know what item you added to the OC ("full control"), you use that same item to locate it in the ListBox, and you use whatever else you need to do to "inform" the reader (select it; scroll it into view; whatever). (P.S. MVVM concerns are of no concerns to me when it comes to satisfying the needs of an "end user").

@GerrySchmitz, thanks for your responses. I hadn't actually contemplated selecting the item - that may be all that's necessary to get the screen reader to announce. I will need to check the current functionality of the application to see if this has any impact on existing scenarios, for example if the user already has an item selected then selecting a new item would be a bad user experience for this particular application. Might be a few days before I'm able to check this though.

You're the one creating the user experience. If the ListBox is the issue, e.g. "concurrent access", then you need to redesign the UI. I mean, why can't you simply announce "new data has arrived"; which then begs the question: what is the user to do with this new information. Maybe you need a "snapshot" view and a "dynamic" view.

Just answering my own question in the hope someone else might find it useful.
I resolved it via code behind, rather than in the view model. To do this you need to ensure the ListBox is given a name, so you can access it from the code behind.
Because the ListBox control didn't have an obvious change event. I found I could cast the ListBox.Items to INotifyCollectionChanged which gave me access to the CollectionChanged event. Once I got that event it was easy enough to get the AutomationPeer and trigger the LiveRegionChanged event.
To avoid overcomplicating the answer I have only included the view details as there's no change to the view model:
XAML
<Window x:Class="WpfAppAccessibilityTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppAccessibilityTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <!--Ensure you give the list a name so you can access it in code behind-->
        <ListBox Name="MyListBox" AutomationProperties.LiveSetting="Assertive" AutomationProperties.Name="My list of things" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStuff}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Code Behind
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MyViewModel();

            if (MyListBox.Items is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyList)
            {
                notifyList.CollectionChanged += NotifyList_CollectionChanged;
            }
        }

        private void NotifyList_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    var peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(MyListBox);
                    peer?.RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

